# Dynamically scale Bootstrap3 content (mainly text) to display width? Aka responsive text size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, font-size

Bootstrap3's column obviously scale according to the display size, but is it also possible to scale a piece of text in the same way?

It seems I can only set the font-size, but then whether a word or sentence will fit on screen also depends on the content (number of characters).

Is it possible to dynamically scale a piece of text, so that it fits on screen or in a Bootstrap3 grid?

Answer (score 0):

Use of the text-overflow property:

```
#div1 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div2 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

<p>The following two divs contains a long text that will not fit in the box. As you can see, the text is clipped.</p>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:clip":</p>
<div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I fail to see how I can turn this into a solution to my problem? Suppose I have a Bootstrap3 row (at full display width) with php generated content, e.g. "Welcome $userName". What should I do to make this text scale and fit within the available horizontal space? (Also meaning that if I resize my browser window or rotate my mobile device, the display width changes, and thus the text size should adjust accordingly to still fit)

Comment: I think my answer wil solve you problem, it does not matter it is in PHP :)

Comment: I don't see how setting a font size (wether it be in px or em or % units) takes into account the size or length of the entire text? Font size mainly relates to the size *per character*. I mentioned php to indicate that I don't even know the text (or its length or number of characters) in advance. So by only setting the font size, I'd say there is no way of knowing the entire text will fit or match the current display width, or is there..?